# No platform available for current project

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10-seattle

Maybe someone has any idea why when I created new FireMonkey project, I am getting error: `No platform available for current project.`? I've installed Android SDK, but in Delphi options, under SDK Manager list is empty... and when I try to add new SDK, the lists in add dialog are empty... but the same error occures after trying to create VCL application, so the problem has to be somewhere else.

**Rad Studio 10 Seattle Update 1, freshly installed.**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you already checked [this](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Activating_and_Configuring_the_Target_Platform)?

Comment: I have installed Android SDK and all required components, but can not add new platform as described in that article, because can't create new project at all... the error "no platforms avalable for current project" appears when creating new project... and there is nothing on the project menu. But the same happens when I try to create VCL app.

Comment: Do you have active subscription for RAD Studio or do you simply own RAD Studio 10 Seattle? You see there are two versions of RAD Studio 10 Seattle Update 1 instalation available. One for those with active subscription (include all fixes and several new features) and one for those who simply bought RAD Studio 10 Seattle (includes only the biggest bug fixes). Now installing the wrong one could lead to RAD Studio to be broken. More info about this can be found here (http://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/2015-november-radstudio-10seattle-udpate1.html)

Comment: I got genuine license and it is update1 iso, not a patch... license works during installation, so I guess it is for this product... because when I tried to install iso without update, it did not work. Said that it's not for that product. Pretty weird IMHO. All this may be connected to that I had previously XE6 installed ... but any way to fix it without reinstalling Windows? XE6 sees all SDKs and there is no problem with it.

Comment: This would constitute an installation issue, and for that you can get free support from Embarcadero by opening a [support ticket](http://support.embarcadero.com).

Comment: Have you tried this? http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Adding_a_Windows_10_SDK Maybe you need to add a Windows 10 SDK?

Comment: Scratch that, what worked for me was uninstalling and reinstalling RAD Studio from Programs and Features in Windows. Weird...

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue a couple of times with different Delphi IDEs including latest Delphi 10.3.1 Rio, and that's how I got here.
Although I don't know what causes it, I suspect that something missing or corrupted in the registry regarding Delphi install.
I solved it opening RegEdit.exe, navigating to

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\20.0

(It might be also in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE and the number relates to the installed Delphi version. In this example, 20 = Delphi 10.3 Rio)

and renaming it to

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\20.0_OLD

which forces Delphi to recreate it next time it starts. The drawback is that you loose all your settings and installed components (but you can later export specific parts of the old corrupted key, edit it manually in notepad and import it again into the newly created key).
Anyway it is better than reinstalling Delphi. If this procedure doesn't solve the issue, you can restore the original key and have the IDE the way it was.

Answer (score 0):

This is a year too late, and I can't find the Embarcadero forum entry where I read this, but the issue was solved by de-installing then re-installing Seattle, and the first time used, run as administrator.